# Get the difference of two columns with an offset/rolling/shift of 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series, rolling-computation

Stupid question: I have two columns `A` and `B` and would like to create a `new_col`, which is actually the difference between the current `B` and the previous `A`. Previous e.g. means the row before the current row. How can this be achieved (maybe even with a variable offset)?

Target:

```
df
| A | B  | new_col  |
|---|----|----------|
| 1 | 2  | nan (or2)|
| 3 | 4  | 3        |
| 5 | 10 | 7        |
```

Pseudo code:

```
new_col[0] = B[0] - 0
new_col[1] = B[1] - A[0]
new_col[2] = B[2] - A[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.shift`:

```
df['new_col'] = df['B'] - df['A'].shift()

   A   B  new_col
0  1   2      NaN
1  3   4      3.0
2  5  10      7.0
```

Comment: Obvious.. Yes - I was suck into the dataframe option `rolling(..)`